# Swift initialise array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a plist with an array of dictionaries, I'm trying to initialise an array so then I can access each dictionary in the array, but not sure how to.

In Objective-c I'd usually use `NSArray *array = [plist objectForKey:@"Root"];` then use `NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];` then `NSString *string = [dictionary valueForKey@"title"];`

This is what I'm trying to achieve but with the array as a global variable which can be used in all functions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your property list file you can use this

```
// check the URL (URL related API is recommended)
if let tipsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Tips", withExtension:"plist") {
  // read the property list file and cast the type to native Swift 'Dictionary'
  let tipsPlist = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: tipsURL) as! [String:AnyObject]
  // get the array for key 'Category 1', 
  // casting the result to '[[String:String]]` avoids further type casting
  let categoryArray = tipsPlist["Category 1"] as! [[String:String]]
  // iterate thru the expected array and print all values for 'Title' and 'Tip'
  for category in categoryArray {
    print(category["Title"]!)
    print(category["Tip"]!)
  }
} else {
  // if the plist file does not exist, give up
  fatalError("Property list file Tips.plist does not exist")
}
```

or to consider all keys in the root object

```
if let tipsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Tips", withExtension:"plist") {
  let tipsPlist = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: tipsURL) as! [String:AnyObject]
  for (_, categoryArray) in tipsPlist  {
    for category in categoryArray as! [[String:String]] {
      print(category["Title"]!)
      print(category["Tip"]!)
    }
  }
} else {
  fatalError("Property list file Tips.plist does not exist")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, exactly what i wanted, lastly how would I declare categoryArray so it can be accessed from other functions.

Comment: Actually the object  which contains the categories (`Category 1`, `Category 2` etc.) is a dictionary, not an array. In your question with the given property list `NSArray *array = [plist objectAtIndex:0]` cannot work at all if `plist` is the root object.

Comment: Yeah just realised first object is a dictionary too, fixed question.

Comment: There is no (physical) key `Root`, it's only virtual when displayed in the Editor as property list. Select "Open as Source Code" to see the actual contents.

Comment: Ok sorted, any idea how to declare categoryArray so it can be accessed from other functions?

Comment: I don't understand, the code shows how to get the several nested objects from the property list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var aDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "plist") {
    aDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let aDict = aDict {
    let str = aDict["title"]
    print(str) // prints "I am a title."
}
```

for a .plist file such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I am a title.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

PS: [Global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: I added an image of my plist.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. :-)

Comment: I appreciate that, I clearly know how to do this in Objective-C try to port across to Swift, been at it two days so finally resorted to stackoverflow